# Cannot find resource in dimens

Tags: android

The resource cannot be found. Here is my resource:

dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="recyclerview_padding">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

In my fragment I tried each of the following:

```
val padding = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.recyclerview_padding) as Int

val padding = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.recyclerview_padding) as Int

val padding = activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.recyclerview_padding) as Int
```

I also tried cleaning my project but this did not work.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question. Is the file stored in the res/values folder?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should get the value

```
<resources>
<dimen name="recyclerview_padding">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

dimens.xml

```
val dimenFromXml = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.recyclerview_padding) // Int
```

It will be in `Float` by default
or you can use `getDimensionPixelOffset` which will convert it to `Int`

```
val dimenFromXml = resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.recyclerview_padding) // Float
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `(Int)` cast, as it says in the [`getDimension(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension(int)) it expects an `Int` as a parameter but it returns a `Float`

> Returns
>   float   Resource dimension value multiplied by the appropriate metric to convert to pixels.

```
val myDimen = activity?.resources?.getDimension(R.dimen.recyclerview_padding)
```

Answer (score 0):

go File->Invalidate cache/restart

Answer (score 0):

Using "as Int" is wrong. This is correct:

```
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.recyclerview_padding).toInt()
```

Oddly, if you just evaluate:

```
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.recyclerview_padding)
```

it generates a "Resource not found" exception.

Comment: there's an alternate method for that `getDimensionPixelOffset` check my updated answer @AndroidDev

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.recyclerview_padding)
```